# How to use RetryInterceptorBuilder.StatefulRetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-retry

I have the configuration for the RabbitMQ as follow for stateful retry:

```
@Bean
    public StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor  statefulRetryOperationsInterceptor(CustomMessageRecoverer customRecoverer) {
        StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor =
                RetryInterceptorBuilder.StatefulRetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()
                        .maxAttempts(2)
                        .recoverer(customRecoverer)
                        .build();
        return interceptor;
    }


@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory queueListenerConnectionFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(this.minConsumersCount);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(this.maxConsumersCount);
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    factory.setAdviceChain(statefulRetryOperationsInterceptor(messageRecoverer(rabbitTemplate(connectionFactory()))));
    return factory;
}
```

My message header has ID set into it. However, When an exception is thrown by the Rabbit listener the retry is not happening. Following is my listener

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
public void consume(Message<MyDto> msg) throws Exception {
throw new Exception("Test Exception");
}
```

Anything wrong in my implementation? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@RabbitListener` is using the default `rabbitListenerContainerFactory`, not your `queueListenerConnectionFactory`.

If you don't need the default one, rename yours to `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` or use the `containerFactory` property on the listener to tell it to use yours.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I forgot to mention `containerFactory="queueListenerConnectionFactory"` in my question. On further investigation I could see in one of your comment in some another question stateful will work only for `AcknowledgeMode.AUTO`. My use case is strictly for `AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL` mode so stateful will not be able to satisfy my requirement. Please share your thought, my use case is Retry option with `AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL` Stateless is already an option available but want to check further more options.

Comment: Using stateful doesn't really gain you much, but it will work with manual as long as you `channel.basicReject(...)` before throwing the exception. But why do you need MANUAL? It's quite rare to use that.

Comment: Taking into the consideration of retry mechanism. Both statefull and stateless  block the thread for the time span set in Backoff option which is reducing the throughput tremendously. So we configure ack mode as manual and use another parking queue with TTL configure, reading x-death count for number of retries.And after certain retries msg will send to DLQ. In Auto mode this will not be possible and backing the with Thread block disadvantage we are going for manual.Please suggest if we could leverage the Auto retry without the thread blocking.

Comment: You can set `defaultRequeueRejected=false` and any exception thrown will send the message to the DLQ; or you can throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` to reject (and other exceptions to requeue). With stateful retry, throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` from the recoverer.